# Integrating & Extending .NET Identity Classes in EF (Code first)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity-3

I am starting an entirely new .NET MVC project, using code-first against EF 6 and .NET 4.5. I want to use Identity framework also, and extend the Identity base classes within the context configuration for my project. (Not sure I am stating that all correctly... I am a seasoned C#/.NET developer that's somewhat new to MVC, EF, and Identity.)

My problem: something's quite wrong. In attempting to generate a new migration, I am getting errors:

```
POST.Data.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
POST.Data.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

Okay, so, I have two contexts in my project, one for the Identity classes, the other for everything else. Same database, and nothing from either of the contexts refers to anything in the other. I define the entities thusly:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser { }
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole { }
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole { }
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim { }
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin { }
```

Then, I have a context class like this:

```
public partial class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public IdentityContext() : base() { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(ul => ul.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(ur => new { ur.RoleId, ur.UserId });
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserClaim> ApplicationUserClaims { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserLogin> ApplicationUserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure it even matters, but my configuration thing looks like this:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<POST.Data.Models.Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"ContextMigrations";
    }

    protected override void Seed(POST.Data.Models.Context context) {}
}
```

That will build, but I can't generate the migration without those errors, and with my limited knowledge and understanding of all the details, I'm baffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not extending any of the identity entities for user, role etc I wouldn't bother creating your own identity subclasses (ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, etc). You also don't need to define any identity related DbSets on your context as they're automatically inherited from IdentityDbContext. However if you want to keep your identity subclasses your DbContext should inherit from the generic IdentityDbContext as this allows you to define your custom identity entities:

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
   // Define other non-identity related dbsets
}
```

This will ensure your DbContext automatically has all of the relevant DbSet properties without having to explicitly define them as they're inherited from the generic IdentityDbContext<> class.

You also shouldn't need to define any migrations or fluent api configuration in the OnModelCreating for any of the identity stuff since you're not adding anything to the identity entities (e.g. additional ApplicationUser properties). The default identity tables will be created automatically when the DbContext/EF is initialised.

Comment: Okay, so this was the original direction I was taking but created separate subclasses because I was thinking that I would want to extend them in the future and I may as well make my life easy now. But I see the logic in just leaving it alone, honestly.

Comment: But the question I have, and I hope I word this correctly, is: if I don't have a separate context that inherits from IdentityDbContext and, instead, just inherits from DbContext, then how are the base Identity classes even being created at all, such that those concrete entities will in turn get generated in my database? I mean, at some point I need to say that I want the AspNet Identity tables to get created, right? So: how? I have my other context like MainContext:DbContext; should that be MainContext:IdentityDbContext?

Comment: Okay, never mind. I do believe I have this figured-out... :-P  You just create the separate context and leave it empty.

Comment: They won't be generated unless you inherit from one of the IdentityDbContext classes (generic or not). Yes the general approach would be for MainContext to inherit from IdentityDbContext rather than having separate contexts so that everything can be queried/inserted/updated etc together

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, since it does in fact solve my "problem," and helped me toward a better understanding of what I am doing. But I'd also like to point-out that Uilique's answer below is also valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set Entities key using the attribute [`Key`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Something like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YourCompany.YourProject.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim { }

    public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin { }
}
```

I hope it helps you and if it does, plese mark it as answer ;)

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of this but didn't try it because I assumed those were already marked in the foundation classes as keys... This gets me closer, as the initial errors I was receiving have disappeared, yes. But I'm getting build warnings now in regards to the hiding (should I use override?) and my migration still won't create on account of: "The item with identity 'Id' already exists in the metadata collection.
Parameter name: item"